# Reading configurations from xml file in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I am developing web application using spring mvc 4 REST API, where I have web.xml file and spring-servlet.xml file.

I am using host/ip and port numbers in between my code, instead I should config in xml file and read it in controller.

That shouldn't overload my application. It shouldn't break the MVC structure/policies.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions is to put the configurations in the properties files, and then adopted by the spring xml files. Below is an example:

```
###Redis Settings###
redis.pool.maxActive=1024
redis.pool.maxIdle=200
redis.pool.maxWait=1000
redis.pool.testOnBorrow=true 
redis.ip=redis-server
redis.port=6379
```

Then:

```
<!-- Configuration for Properties -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/config/redis.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configuration for Redis Client -->
<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="maxActive" value="${redis.pool.maxActive}" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${redis.pool.maxIdle}" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="${redis.pool.maxWait}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${redis.pool.testOnBorrow}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${redis.ip}" />
    <property name="port" value="${redis.port}" />
    <property name="poolConfig" ref="jedisPoolConfig" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate" p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory">
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. Can i place that properties file inside WEB-INF(where i have spring-servlet.xml). If so how should i config the path in spring-servlet.xml file

Comment: and how to use the maxActive in class